# Search for strings in a list that have > 90% similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, time-limit-exceeded, edit-distance

**Explanation:**
I am working on String comparison in which I want to cross-compare the list of the same input string.
For the same string, I am continuing the loop but if a single string will have similarity greater than 90% than it should not be appended to the refined Input list. The code on which I am working is down there:

**Source Code:**

```
from DatabaseOperations import DatabaseOperations
import csv
from similarity.jarowinkler import JaroWinkler

def refineInputFileData(inputList):
    jarowinkler = JaroWinkler()
    refinedInputList = []
    refinedDict = {}
    for outer_keyword in inputList:
        if outer_keyword == "-":
            refinedInputList.append(outer_keyword)
            continue
        for inner_keyword in inputList:
            if outer_keyword == inner_keyword:
                continue

            similarity = jarowinkler.similarity(outer_keyword, inner_keyword)
            match_percentage = similarity * 100

            if (match_percentage >= 90):
                break
            else:
                refinedDict[outer_keyword] = ""
                refinedInputList.append(outer_keyword)
    return refinedInputList
if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputList = getInputDataList()
    print(inputList)
    refineList = refineInputFileData(inputList)
```

**Data List:**

```
inputList = ['2018 form 1040 schedule 1', '2018 schedule 1', '2018 form 1040 schedule 2', '2018 form 1040 schedule a', 'schedule 1 2018', '2018 form 1040 schedule 3', '2018 form 1040 schedule 1 instructions', '2018 form 1040 schedule 4', '2018 form 1040 schedule 5', '1040 schedule 1', '2018 schedule 2', '1040 line 11', '2018 1040 schedule 1', '2018 schedule 1 instructions', '2018 schedule 3', '2018 schedule 5', '2018 1040 schedule a', '1040 line 12', 'form 1040 line 11', 'schedule 1 tax form 2018', 'schedule 2 2018', 'schedule 5 2018', '1040 schedule a 2018', 'schedule 3 tax form 2018', 'schedule 1 line 22', 'form 1040 schedule 1', 'schedule 2 tax form 2018', 'schedule 3 2018', 'schedule 4 tax form 2018', '1040 form 2018 schedule 1', '1040 line 9', '1040 schedule 1 2018', '2018 form 1040 schedule 6', '2018 form 1040 schedules', '2018 1040 schedule 2', '1040 form 2018 schedule a', 'schedule 5 tax form 2018', 'new 1040 schedules', 'form 1040 schedule a 2018', 'schedule 1040 for 2018', 'schedule 1 instructions 2018', '2018 schedule 1040', 'new schedule a', 'irs schedule 1 2018', 'new form 1040 schedules', 'line 22 schedule 1', 'irs schedule 3', 'irs 2018 schedule 1', 'form 1040 schedules 2018', 'new tax schedules 1 6', '2018 schedule a form 1040', '2018 federal tax schedule 1', 'form 1040 schedule 3', '2018 tax form schedule 3', 'what is schedule 1 tax form', 'irs schedule e instructions', '2018 tax return schedule', '1040 schedules 2018', '1040 schedule e instructions', 'schedule a tax form 2018', 'form 1040 schedule e pdf', 'what is schedule 4 other taxes', 'schedule 3 of income tax act', '2018 schedule se', '2018 irs schedule 1', '2018 form 1040 schedule e', 'how to fill out 1040 form 2018', 'schedule e instructions 2018', '2018 schedule a tax form', 'what will the 2018 1040 look like', '2018 form 1040 draft', 'new irs schedules', 'irs form schedule e form 1040', 'irs schedule se instructions', 'tax schedule e 2018', 'what is schedule e form 1040', '2018 tax year schedule a', 'proposed new tax form', 'irs 2018 forms schedule 1', '2018 tax forms schedule a', 'irs schedule one', 'new irs schedule 1', '1040 schedule e 2018', 'tax season 2018 schedule', 'irs form schedule a 2018', 'new tax schedules for 2018', 'schedule se instructions 2018', 'what is schedule e in tax return', 'irs 1040 line 21', 'schedule se 2018 instructions', 'irs gov schedule se', '2018 schedule e instructions', 'irs 2018 schedule a', 'form 1040 schedule e line 16 instructions', 'schedules 1 6 irs', 'irs schedule 3 for 2018', 'schedule e tax return', '2018 draft 1040', '2017 form 1040 schedule e', '2018 instructions schedule c', 'Keyword', '2018 irs schedule 1 form', 'irs schedule e 2018', 'schedule 3 income tax act', 'form 1040 line 12b', 'schedule a form 2018', 'irs 1040 schedule 2', '2018 schedule 4 instructions', '2018 tax forms schedule 1', '2018 schedule a form', 'form 1040 schedule e instructions', 'irs gov schedule c instructions', 'schedule one tax form', 'irs form 1040 schedule e for 2018', 'final 1040 form 2018', 'irs schedule 5 for 2018', 'tax schedule a 2018']
```

Answer (score 2):

Specific suggestions:

1. `main` doesn't do anything with `refineList`.
2. Rather than multiply by 100 a bunch of times you can simply check `similarity >= 0.9`
3. The threshold should be configurable. You have many options for that, including at least a mandatory or optional parameter (using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)) or a configuration file (using [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)).
4. In the same vein the list of inputs could be taken from lines (or NUL-separated strings) in standard input.
5. Why is there special casing for `outer_keyword == "-"`?
6. `refinedDict` is superfluous - it's set but never read.
7. Since `match_percentage >= 90` is the last check in that loop you can get rid of the `else` clause:

   ```
   if similarity < 0.9:
       refined_input_list.append(outer_keyword)
   ```

General suggestions:

1. [`black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) can automatically format your code to be more idiomatic.
2. [`isort`](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort) can group and sort your imports automatically.
3. [`flake8`](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8) with a strict complexity limit will give you more hints to write idiomatic Python:

   ```
   [flake8]
   max-complexity = 4
   ignore = W503,E203
   ```
4. I would then recommend adding [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) everywhere and validating them using a strict [`mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy) configuration:

   ```
   [mypy]
   check_untyped_defs = true
   disallow_untyped_defs = true
   ignore_missing_imports = true
   no_implicit_optional = true
   warn_redundant_casts = true
   warn_return_any = true
   warn_unused_ignores = true
   ```